# Not able to cover complete service.ts in nestjs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have nestjs members.service.ts file

```
import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { FinanceMemberDocument } from './members.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { MemberType } from './members.types';
import { MemberDto } from './dto/members.dto';

@Injectable()
export class MembersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('finance_members')
    private readonly financeMembersModel: Model<FinanceMemberDocument>,
  ) {}

  async getMemberDetails(memberGuid: string): Promise<MemberDto> {
    try{
      const memberArray = await this.financeMembersModel
        .find({ guid: memberGuid })
        .sort({ _id: -1 })
        .limit(1);
      return memberArray[0];
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw new HttpException({ ...err }, err?.response?.status);
    }
  }
}
```

this is my members.service.spec.ts file

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MembersService } from './members.service';
import { MemberType } from './members.types';
import { memberData } from './mockMembersData';

class MemberServiceMock {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  getMemberDetails(_memberId: string) {
    return memberData;
  }
}

describe('MembersService', () => {
  let membersService: MembersService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const ApiServiceProvider = {
      provide: MembersService,
      useClass: MemberServiceMock,
    };
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [MembersService, ApiServiceProvider],
    }).compile();
    membersService = await module.get<MembersService>(MembersService);
  });

  it('should is defined', () => {
    expect(membersService).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('is not null', () => {
    expect(typeof membersService.getMemberDetails).not.toBeNull();
  });

  it('should get data', async () => {
    try{
    const data = await membersService.getMemberDetails('123');
    expect(data).toEqual(memberData);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  });
  

  it('empty member detail', async () => {
    await expect(membersService.getMemberDetails('123')).toMatchObject({});
  });
});
```

This is my jest lcov HTML report
[image]

I tried lots of things but not able to cover the complete service file. is there any way to cover everything in the service.ts file?
Please help me to cover my service code atleast 80%

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test/cover `MemberService` and you should not mock it by providing `MemberServiceMock`. Instead you should mock the service's dependecies, in this case `financeMembersModel`.

Note that there's a library for mocking mongoose models which you can use if you don't want to write the mock yourself -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockingoose

Comment: @user562451: any feedback?